# Border dispute on Ansion

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In **Attack of the clones**, Jedi Master Mace Windu said that Obi-Wan Kenobi *returned from a border dispute on Ansion*. The said event references what happens in the novel **The Approaching Storm**, but since this novel, and its events, is not canon anymore but the planet still, what do we know about this border dispute and the planet in general.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ansion

Comment: But what about that dispute?

Comment: Mentioned in the film, not elsewhere, as far as I know